# Limited WAN speed through Linksys E4200 running DD-WRT

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

Today we have upgraded our internet connection from 90 Mbps to 180 Mbps, only to find out speedtest.net will not give a result higher than ~96 Mbps.

If I connect directly to the modem, bypassing the router, I get the full 180.

The ethernet connection on my PC is `Realtek RTL8168D/8111D`, our router is a `Linksys E4200 v1`, and it's running `DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) mega`. I have a CAT6 cable.

Manually setting the link speed on the computer to 1Gbit does not make a difference.

How can I find out if there's a particular setting that is affecting the speed, and which one? Most of the things I find on Google relate to tweaking WiFi settings for a better speed, or refer to QoS, which is already disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the Pc is plugged into the router, does the link speed say it's Gb full duplex? Even if it does, have you tried hard setting the negotiation speeds instead of leaving it to auto-detect?

Comment: Yes it does, and yes I did. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Can you confirm that the link from the modem to the router is running at gigabit speed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Any suggestions for how I can verify this?

Comment: There's likely an indicator on each end that lights up a different color if the link is gigabit.

Comment: From @Marcelo: Could it be that somehow the connection either from modem-router or router-PC is failing back to 100Mb (normal ethernet) instead of 1Gb ethernet?  Does the router have a 1G WAN port?  Looks like dd-wrt may have an issue with E4200?  http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=178671&sid=521c90fd56695e2f2f72cbaaa5599848

Answer (score 0):

Your using a version of DDWRT that is built by brainslayer, if you use a later version (e.g one made by Kong) you'll find that this will be resolved, however in the Kong veversion I have, I found that the VPN was broke agaagain.. However Tis a small price to pay for the fact of the speeds you'll gain.